# Google Sheet query all rows on today's date

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a Google spreadsheet document with two sheets in it. The first sheet is where I want to run my query.

Located in cell A1 is today's date with the formula `=today()`. I want the query to start in A2. My information is in the second sheet cells A2:I.

I want the query to pull Columns B to I. Column A has the dates. I want to run the query based on today's date and match all the dates in Column A of the second sheet and return the values.

Also is it possible to do this with tomorrow's date?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=query(second!A2:I,"select B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I where A = date '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

and either `=today()` or `=today()+1` in A1. The dates in ColumnA of your second sheet must be formatted as dates, not text.